# Re-import my project, all scripts and terrain are disappear, how can I slove this problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My computer broke down, and I replaced a computer to import my project, as shown in the link, all the terrain of the material disappeared, may I ask what happened?[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOXVk.jpg)

This is my terrain hierachy: 
[terrain hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3sYc.jpg)

Comment: I think we need more information. Where is your terrain in the project folder view? Can you show the terrain in the hierarchy? Did the material disappear, or the terrain itself?

Comment: They are still in the folder, but cannot be displayed, just like the tank in my picture, which also has to delete the material package in the file and then import again to see.

Comment: Did you re-import it into the EXACT same version of Unity?

Comment: Try and do a reimport on all your assets. This happens something when jumping from one unity version to an other. In unity right click on the Assets folder (root) -> reimport all. It can take a while to run if you have a lot of assets.

Comment: Re-import did not work. Yes, I re-import it in different version, how could I know my previous version?